# Let $H,K\lhd G$, if $H\cong K$ and $H\cap K\neq\{1\}$ then does it follow that $H=K?$

Tags: group-theory

Let $H,K\lhd G$, if $H\cong K$ and $H\cap K\neq\{1\}$ then does it follow that $H=K?$

It is clear that if $H\cap K=\{1\}$ then $H$ need not be equal to $K$ . But if it follows that there intersection isn't empty, does it follow that they must be equal?

Comment: Take a couple of 4-element subgroups of the group of symmetries of a square.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. As a simple counterexample take $G=\mathbb Z^3$, $H=\{0\}\times\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$, and $K=\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z\times\{0\}$.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a **Non Abelian Counterexample**:

Consider the quaternion group $Q_8=\{1, i, j, k, -1, -i, -j, -k\}$ .

In particular we have the relations $i^2=j^2=k^2=-1$ and $i^4=j^4=k^4=1$.

So take the subgroups $I= \langle i \rangle$ ang $J=\langle j \rangle$ that are normal (they have index 2 as subgroups of $Q_8$).

We have $I \cap J = \{1, -1\}$ and $I \neq J$ as we need.

Answer (score 2):

No, it just follows that their intersection is a normal subgroup of all $G$, $H$ and $K$.

Comment: Could you please produce a counterexample?

Answer (score 2):

Take the abelian group of order $8$ which is the direct product of three groups of order $2$ generated by $a,b,c$. Consider the groups generated by $a,b$ and $a,c$.

For that matter take $G=A\times B\times B$ and take the two obvious subgroups of form $A\times B$